# Execution orders of SQL aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sales table in SQLite:

| purchase_date | units_sold | customer_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 1 | 1 |
| 17 | 1 | 1 |
| 30 | 3 | 1 |

I want to get the total `unit_solds` for each customer on the first date and last date of their purchases. My query is:

```
  select customer_id,
         sum(units_sold) total_units_sold
    from sales
group by customer_id
  having purchase_date = min(purchase_date) 
      or purchase_date = max(purchase_date)
```

I was expecting results like:

| customer_id | total_units_sold |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |

but I got:

| customer_id | total_units_sold |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |

I would like to know why this solution doesn't work.

Comment: Please tag only one DBMS, not four different ones.

Comment: Please can you share which type of database you are using, for some reason different dialects may treat your query differently, my thoughts on this though are that purchase date in the having clause is not specified in the group by and is technically an "unknown".  You would need to include purchase date in your group by

Comment: ok thanks. will be careful next time

Comment: The having clause happens after the selected data I think. So the summation already happened before you filter it with the having clause.

Comment: Just an fyi, the `HAVING` clause is probably not valid, since `purchase_date` is not functionally dependent on the `GROUP BY` terms.  sqlite might not detect that issue.  Think about it.  Each customer could have multiple sales on different dates.  `GROUP BY customer_id` wouldn't necessarily be associated with one `purchase_date`.  `MAX(purchase_date)` is perfectly fine in the `HAVING` clause, but not just `purchase_date`.  The `HAVING` clause operates on the groups, not any individual rows in `sales`.

Comment: Try `select customer_id, purchase_date from sales group by customer_id`. Sqlite allows that purchase_date isn't part of the group by, which deviates from standard SQL. The having is comparing the MIN & MAX to 1 date only.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the phrase is incorrect
Note: The having statement is executed after compilation.

You need to get the results as partial queries
For example, I arranged to know the first line of the date according to each customer
as well as the last line of the date (by getting the first line after descending order)
and then execute the group statement

The example is complete

```
      select customer_id,sum(units_sold) from (
         select customer_id, units_sold,purchase_date,
            ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by customer_id order by purchase_date) As RowDatefirst,
            ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by customer_id order by purchase_date desc)As RowDatelast    
         from sales
         ) t where t.RowDatefirst = 1 or t.RowDatelast=1
       group by customer_id
```

Comment: Thanks. I was under the impression that having is executed before select

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT a.customer_id, SUM(a.units_sold) as total_units_sold
FROM sales a
INNER JOIN (
       SELECT customer_id, MIN(purchase_date) as _first ,MAX(purchase_date) as _last
       FROM sales
       GROUP BY customer_id
) b ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id AND
      (a.purchase_date = b._first OR a.purchase_date = b._last)
GROUP BY a.customer_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/0a4a4/7